# SQL using UPDLOCK in query to update top 1 record after filtering and ordering table

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RV_SM_WORKITEM_CHECKWORKBYTYPE] 
( 
    @v_ServiceName Nvarchar(20)
    ,@v_WorkType Nvarchar(20)
    ,@v_WorkItemThreadId nvarchar(50)
) 
AS BEGIN
    ;WITH updateView AS 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 * 
        FROM rv_sm_workitem WITH (UPDLOCK) 
        WHERE stateofitem = 0 
          AND itemtype = @v_worktype 
        ORDER BY ITEMPRIORITY
    )
    UPDATE updateView
    SET assignedto = @v_ServiceName, 
        stateofitem = 1, 
        dateassigned = getdate(), 
        itemthreadid = @v_WorkItemThreadId
    OUTPUT INSERTED.* 
END
```

It does the job I need it to do, namely, grab 1 record with a highest priority, change it's state from Available(0) to Not-Available(1), and return the record for work to be done with it. I should be able to have many threads (above 20) use this proc and have all 20 constantly running/grabbing a new workitem. However I am finding that beyond 2 threads, addition threads are waiting on locks; I'm guessing the UPDLOCK is causing this.

I have 2 questions, is there a better way to do this?

Can I do this without the UPDLOCK in the cte since the update statement by default uses UPDLOCK? Note, at any given time, there are over 400,000 records in this table.

Comment: Query hints in general should be avoided except for absolute last ditch efforts and even then only when they are truly understood. When you use a locking hint like this you are telling sql server that you know better how to handle locks than the engine does. This is rarely the case. I would just remove that hint and see if the issue doesn't resolve itself.

Comment: In [this article](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) Remus Rusanu discusses similar case (using delete instead of update), but uses (rowlock, readpast) query hints to improve concurrency. See Table Hints readpast entry in Books online: `A queue reader that uses READPAST skips past queue entries locked by other transactions to the next available queue entry, without having to wait until the other transactions release their locks.)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to so something similar once and this is what I would suggest:

```
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @results table (id int, otherColumns varchar(50))
  WHILE (EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @results))
  BEGIN
    ;WITH updateView AS 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 * 
        FROM rv_sm_workitem
        WHERE stateofitem = 0 
          AND itemtype = @v_worktype 
        ORDER BY ITEMPRIORITY
    )
    UPDATE updateView
    SET assignedto = @v_ServiceName, 
        stateofitem = 1, 
        dateassigned = getdate(), 
        itemthreadid = @v_WorkItemThreadId
    OUTPUT INSERTED.* into @results
    where stateofitem = 0
 END
END
```

This ensures that the call cannot not allow a item to be double processed. (because of the where clause on the update statement).

There are other variations of this idea, but this is an easy way to convey it.  This is not production ready code though, as it will continually circle in the while loop until there is something to process.  But I leave it to you to decide how to break out or not loop and return empty (and let the client side code deal with it.)

Here is the [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/117189/6383) that helped me when I had this issue.